# Update MYSQL table via BASH script give syntax error

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to run an update query on a db server via bash command.
I have to update an IP field (which is sorted as a string) but i'm getting a syntax error...

```
ssh admin@192.168.3.240 "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -D SMARTPARK -u parkuser -ppass -e 'update client SET online=0 where client_ip='192.168.42.11''"
```

I'm getting as error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.42.11' at line 1

which is the error?

Comment: There is a difference between quote and double-quote. Use `"update client SET online=0 where client_ip='192.168.42.11'"`

Comment: Actually you need to alternate between `"` and `'` to make sure you don't escape from your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape `"` character with `\"` to make sure you don't escape from the string you're sending to your DB.

In other words, try to put the following in the bash file you're executing:

```bash
ssh admin@192.168.3.240 "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -D SMARTPARK -u parkuser -ppass -e \"update client SET online=0 where client_ip='192.168.42.11'\""
```

Comment: ok, I have no more the error, but the command looks like I ran the -h command because I see all the help prompt and the query is not made...

Comment: @besmart Could you try again with my last edit's suggestion?

Comment: changing to your last edit gives me back syntax error

Comment: @besmart I tried with a script of my own with escaped `"`, i.e. `\"`, it worked just fine.